# Trying to add a user to an environment in AWS Cloud9 I get "Member must satisfy regular expression pattern"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloud9

I am trying to give read-write permissions to an environment in Cloud9 to a user.

I am using `aws cli` for this.

```
$> aws --version
aws-cli/2.9.23 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/22.5.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

I used the following command:

```
$> aws cloud9 create-environment-membership --environment-id <ENVIRONMENT_ID> --user-arn arn:aws:iam::NNNNNNNNNNNN:user/NAME@example.com --permissions read-write
```

Once I execute this on the command line, I get the expected output:

```
{
    "membership": {
        "permissions": "read-write",
        "userId": "NNNNNN",
        "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::NNNNNNNNNNNN:user/NAME@example.com",
        "environmentId": "<ENVIRONMENT_ID>"
    }
}
```

However, when I log into the AWS dashboard on the web, I see the following red error message when I navigate to Cloud9 and click on `All account environments`:

```
AWS Cloud9 is unable to process the request. Please see the following details:
1 validation error detected: Value 'all' at 'environmentId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,32}$
```

I assume the regex complains that I have an `@` symbol in the user's ARN. However, that's part of their username.

Any ideas?

Also, why did it seemingly go through when I ran the `aws cli` command on the command line, but then complains on the web interface?

EDIT: added a screenshot of the error
[image]

Comment: "Value 'all' at 'environmentId'" - '--environment-id <ENVIRONMENT_ID>' - I don't think `<ENVIRONMENT_ID>` is the value you think it is in the console. How are you setting it?

Comment: I went to `AWS Cloud9` -> `Environments` -> `my-environment`. Then I looked at the ARN and took it from there: `arn:aws:cloud9:us-east-1: NNNNNNNNNNNN:environment:<ENVIRONMENT_ID>`

Comment: 'I see the following red error message' - so do you see this visually?

Comment: Yes, it pops up on the web dashboard (see the edit to the original post)